# How to know the active Apache projects?

Tags: apache, project

There are a couple of projects in Apache (including incubator). Some of these projects are abandoned and not updated for years. How to know the active projects in Apache? This would be one of the factor for those who are planning to involve in the Apache development process.

Comment: I guess answer is apache's website!

Answer (score 0):

The below URLs show the list of projects and the last when they were updated.

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/?sortby=date

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/?sortby=date

Comment: It makes sense to know why someone has marked the answer down.